# Matrix template class * operator must generate error

Tags: c++, templates

I have a homework and my teacher told us to create a matrix class with templates.
One specification is, if you try to multiply two matrices with wrong dimensions, 
like Matrix1[100][20] and Matrix2[20][101], the compiler needs to generate a error and not the runtime.

I haven't started this part of the homework because I can't imagine how the compiler will figure out that.

Sorry if that is a dummy question.

Thanks ppl.

Comment: Hint: Template parameters don't have to be types. They can be numbers.

Comment: We need to know more about what you mean here, what does the matrix template actually look like, try to post a short and complete example

Comment: Have you gotten into what templates actually are?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The size of the matrix must be part of the type system, which implies that the dimensions must be passed as template arguments. Ie, `Matrx<100, 20>` is a specific type.

Now when you overload `operator*()`, you can use a pair of template arguments to accept only matrices of the same size in the parameter list, like `(Matrix<N, M> a, Matrix<N, M> b)`.

Comment: Except the dimensions should be flipped on one of the matrices.

Comment: @juanchopanza I actually wasn't sure whether the OP wanted linear-algebra multiplication or element-by-element multiplication. The question seems to indicate that matrices of size 100*20 and 20*101 cannot be multiplied together.